# Check whether user is connected to WiFi or Mobile Data while the lock screen is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to find some information on how you would know whether the user has WiFi enabled or whether they are on mobile data **WHILE** they are on the lock screen.  So, the app is in the background, but I want to know the current network connection state.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Are you having trouble accessing the network state while running in this state? What error are you receiving? Or are you just getting wrong information? What tool are you using to read the network state?

Comment: I'm asking how you would go about determining the network state to begin with.  I know there is a Reachability class from Apple.. but.. do we set up a notification somehow to receive messages that the connection has changed?

Comment: The problem here isn't getting network state, it's that you can't run in the background this way. When the device is locked, your app will almost never run, and the system isn't going to notify you. If you *are* running, NWPathMonitor will work fine, but it won't wake you up in the background, whether the screen is locked or not. What you're trying to do is very likely impossible. So the question is what deeper problem you're trying to solve, and for most (though not all) cases we can probably help you find another solution.